# Is this right to say 'job holders'

Tags: collocations

For example; Some think that holders of the jobs such as nurses are less paid.

Is this right to say, what else can I say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther is nothing wrong with "job holders" although "employees" is far more common. However "are less paid" is incorrect. One might write "are paid less" or "are more poorly paid". Both of these are comparative forms, and do not make sense unless some previous sentence gives something (or more likely someone) better paid that "teachers" is being compared to. Or the sentence might be change to include something to compare to "teachers". If no specific object of comparison will be mentioned, then this might be recast as:

> Some think that employees such as teachers are poorly paid.